# How to print all the values in a ThreadLocal HashMap for all the threads?

Tags: java

Is it possible to print out all the values in a ThreadLocal HashMap for all the threads?

Edit: To elaborate further why I want to do this, I have a Spring boot app where the incoming requests are processed on a "http-nio-8080-exec" thread which request uses JobRunr to execute some Jobs (which happens on a "background-worker" thread).

I have logs before creating the Job and inside the job as well, in the log before creating the Job (executed on the "http-nio-8080-exec" processing thread) I put some stuff in the MDC map (which is ThreadLocal) and what I can see is that the information is passed along to the "background-worker" once doing the log inside the Job. I don't know how they are being passed to it (probably some process of JobRunr), what I want to make sure that it is only passed to the right "background-worker" thread and afterwards cleared properly.

Btw I use SLF4J for logging.

Comment: What does this means? *print for all the threads*?

Comment: I want to print out the values for all the running threads at once.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help us to understand what you want to achieve. *printing* is *outputting something outside the process*. So what does it means *printing for all the threads*. Give us some code, explain much clearer what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Just because you don't understand the question doesn't mean it's necessarily the fault of the asker. I understood the question perfectly fine.

Comment: Think about it: your print operation has to happen on some thread. That printer thread only has access to the thread-local that exists on itself, but not on any other threads. So no, in a general way, it's not possible. In a much more limited scenario, e.g. you have a subset of threads which all process requests off of some queues or something, you could put requests onto every thread's queue which say "print your thread-local".

Comment: Aha okay, I understand. I posted further explanation in an edit, maybe you can give me an idea how I can test it out?

Comment: 1) Iterate over all threads; 2) access each thread's package-private variable `threadLocals` (probably via reflection); 3) get your value using private method `threadLocals.getEntry(yourThreadLocal)`, again via reflection.

Comment: I tried but I'm getting an error "Unable to make field java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap java.lang.Thread.threadLocals accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7690781".

Comment: If you are having trouble using reflection with the Java module system, please ask a different question about that. And please search first, because that question gets asked *a lot*.

Answer (score 0):

I had some time to spare, so I made a proof of concept. It's in Kotlin because that's what I had available, but it should be easy to convert to Java:

```kotlin
fun <V> getAllThreadLocalValues(threadLocal: ThreadLocal<V>): Map<Thread, V> {
    val threadLocalsField = Thread::class.java.getDeclaredField("threadLocals")
        .apply { trySetAccessible() }
    val getEntryMethod = Class.forName("java.lang.ThreadLocal\$ThreadLocalMap")
        .getDeclaredMethod("getEntry", ThreadLocal::class.java)
        .apply { trySetAccessible() }
    val entryValueField = Class.forName("java.lang.ThreadLocal\$ThreadLocalMap\$Entry")
        .getDeclaredField("value")
        .apply { trySetAccessible() }

    return Thread.getAllStackTraces().mapValues { (thread, _) ->
        val map = threadLocalsField.get(thread) ?: return@mapValues null
        val entry = getEntryMethod.invoke(map, threadLocal) ?: return@mapValues null
        val value = entryValueField.get(entry) ?: return@mapValues null
        value as V
    }.filterValues { it != null } as Map<Thread, V>
}
```

This code returns a map of `Thread` to the value of the passed `ThreadLocal`, if any. Threads without a value aren't included in the map.

Note that you'll need to pass `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to allow the reflection.